# How would I make an "object" (key-value pair) in C++?

Tags: arduino, key-value

I'm working with Arduino. I want to make an "object". By that, I mean a key-value pair (I'm used to Javascript, all you JS programmers know what I mean). Basically, I want to use something similar to JSON in C++.

I will show you how I would approach my problem if I were using JavaScript:

```js
const timeZones = {
    "London": 0,
    "Paris": 1,
    "Sydney": 10,
    "Los Angeles": -8
}
```

And then I could access a value like this:

```js
let pst = timeZones["LosAngeles"] * 3600;
```

I'm not sure how to do this in C++, though. I looked everywhere, and I could only find things about structs and 2d arrays, which are irrelevant to my problem.

I also found something really close to what I need, but it was a struct in an array or something like that (e.g. `timeZones[3].time` would give me `-8`).

Sorry if this is a super basic question, I just started Arduino 3 days ago.

Comment: take a look at `std::map`

Comment: Or, depending on the behaviour you want, [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: I hope "everywhere" included [cppreference.com](https://www.cppreference.com).

Comment: Oh. Oh shoot. Ardunino. Arduino is awesomely limited. It's Standard Library implementation is, to be charitable, non Standard. You're on your own and have to write your own if you can't find a map implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering about that. Does Arduino not support the standard library?

Comment: Recommendation: Don't learn C++ on an Arduino. What you'll learn is an offspring of C that isn't quite C++.

Comment: @jkb Arduino is a platform for middle-weight embedded systems. It's written to be friendly to CPUs without good memory management and would be quickly run out of RAM by fragmentation by the Standard Library containers.

Comment: An array of struct is what you want.

Comment: Recommendation: Get rid of the strings if possible. You cannot index based on a string in the reduced library you have available without writing code that would give journeyman C++ programmers fits. You would wind up with something that looks like a ladder of if statements comparing the given timezone string with each one in the list one after the other. You do this once to turn the string into a number, and then you pass the number around to use in further look-ups.

Comment: Have you tried `std::pair<key-type, value-type`?

Comment: Also, save yourself a wee bit of work if possible and store the zone offsets in the form you're most likely to use. If you use seconds most of the time, store seconds, not hours. If you need to make the CPU work, make it work as infrequently as possible. Also remember that some timezones use half-hour offsets. That means either you use floating point and flirt with rounding errors (see [is floating point math broken?}(https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4581301) for details) or use a smaller increment than hours.

Comment: Write a very simple `main()` function that loads a data structure of your desire, then outputs the content.  For more fun, add functionality to add the classes to a container, like vector, then sort, then print.  Don't deal with Arduino, until the desktop version works correctly.  Use stub functions as necessary.

Comment: @OnyxWingman The votes are for the question, not you. It means it's not useful. In this case it means you need a better background in the basics of C++, and how and why it is different from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

For Arduinos the answer depends on which board are you using.

The ARM based ones have full STL support so map/unordered_map will work.
Just add the map or unordered_map header and you can use it like that.

```cpp
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, int> timezones {
    { "London", 0 },
    { "Paris",  1 },
    { "Sydney", 10},
    {"Los Angeles", -8},
};

void loop() {
    Serial.println(timezones["London"]);
}
```

On AVR based ones (oldest ones Uno, nano, micro) there is no builtin STL suport, but there are some implementations like ArduinoSTL or Arduino_AVRSTL libraries, but both currently failed to link due to `multiple definition of 'std::nothrow'` so you'll have to fix this or make your own implementation in a style of array of structs and implement lookup for it.

Do you even need that? Some constants might be so much better than relatively costly string lookups:

```cpp
constexpr int TZ_LONDON = 0;
constexpr int TZ_PARIS  = 1;

...

    Serial.println(TZ_PARIS);
```